# Define Interface containing array of objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object that is used in many parts of my code so I want to export it as an interface. My object is like this :

```js
 trueFalse: {'itemList' : Array<{'text'; 'value'}>} = {
    itemList: [
      {text: 'foundItem', value: true},
      {text: 'foundItem', value: false}
    ]
  };
```

I tried to import it this way but it doesn't work :

```js
export interface ITrueFalse {
  text: string = 'foundItem',
  value: boolean
  itemList: Array<{'text';'value'}>
}
```

I want to implement the above interface in some way like this:

```
trueFalse: {'itemList' : ITrueFalse} = {
    itemList : [{},{}]
;
```

As you can see I don't have much idea of typescript interfaces. I've only done basic type definition. So I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Thank you for any suggestions :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
export interface TrueFalseItem {
  text: string;
  value: boolean;
}


export interface TrueFalseListWrapper { // renamed from ITrueFalse
  itemList: TrueFalseItem[];
}
```

You can also write the item type itself inline which is convenient if you only need to refer to it as part of the structure of `TrueFalseListWrapper`

```
export interface TrueFalseListWrapper {
  itemList: { text: string, value: boolean }[];
}
```

Comment: isn't there some way to add he first two together? something like : `export interface TrueFalseItem: [ ] { }`

Comment: Not quite, but see the second example for a single definition version. You may have unnecessary nesting in your data structures if you need an interface like this to describe it.

Comment: I think what I don't understand is `Array<{'text'; 'value'}>` where there is a semicolon inside (the why there isn't it a comma part)

Comment: That is called an object literal type. You can use either a semi-colon or a comma in an object literal _type_. Any type declaration, such as an `interface`,  is comprised of `name: type` elements. When you omit the type of an element, it defaults to `any`. That means that `{ text; value }` is the same type as `{ text: any; value: any }`. The quotes are optional.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142915/discussion-between-bijay-timilsina-and-aluan-haddad).

Answer (score 7):

Here is another solution that I prefer:

```
interface ItemListValue {
  text: string,
  value: boolean,
}

export interface ItemList extends Array<ItemListValue > {

}
```

```
let result: ItemList;
```

With this solution you can use all properties and methods of the Array (like: `length, push(), pop(), splice()` ...)

Comment: Defining an empty interface is misleading and considered a bad practice given the structurally typed nature of TypeScript. Use `export type ItemList = Array<ItemListValue>;` which makes the intent clear and the code clean